# Rails - will paginate not displaying pages correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Have been following the wiki from the git page but unable to see the problem I am having.

will_paginate is showing the first 10 of the landlords correctly but will not render the next page correctly, the first page 'sticks' no matter which page I visit.
I have tried other threads with the similar issue but did not yield the correct result.

**Question**: What am I doing wrong? I have copied what I think is the key code to my issue.

I have a landlord class and in that class I have these lines ...

model..

```
class landlord

 self.per_page = 10
 default_scope order: 'landlords.name ASC'
```

controller..

```
class Landlords_controller
 def index
   @landlords = Landlord.paginate(page: params[:landlord]).search(params[:search])
 end
```

and the view ...

landlords/index.html.erb

```
 <% @landlords.each ..... %>

 <% end %>

 <%= will_paginate @landlords %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect symbol in :

```
@landlords = Landlord.paginate(page: params[:landlord]).search(params[:search])
```

should be

```
@landlords = Landlord.paginate(page: params[:page]).search(params[:search])
```

I love mondays!

Answer (score 0):

Or, use:

```
<%= will_paginate @landlords, param_name: 'landlord' %>
```

This is useful if you have more than one will_paginate on a page, if not, use the default 'page'